# The Pinterest API: Getting followers of a specific board

Tags: api, pinterest

Is it a way to get the followers of a specific board via the Pinterest API? It is possible to see the followers on the site.

What I can see is general board info via https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/

And followers to me via https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/followers/

But /me/followers/ doesn't show which board the followers are following

Answer (score 2):

/v1/boards//

Include 'counts' in the fields requested, and you will get back something like this:

```
root:{} 1 item
    data:{} 4 items
        url:https://www.pinterest.com/<username>/<boardname>/
        counts:{} 3 items
            pins:50
            collaborators:0
            followers:2954  <-- You want this
        id:483292672451505177
        name:<display name>
```